# Traverse Complex JSON with Tree Search Algo in Python

Tags: python, json

This is an example of the json that I working with currently:

http://www.hl7.org/fhir/bundle-transaction.json.html

I have tried a great many approaches to work with this format effectively most of which were total non-starters or computationally unfeasable at scale.  I'm looking for generalized solution ideally.  These json "bundles" contain individual resources from which I would like to extract individual or groups of elements.  It would save time and be easier to follow then having to enumerate every individual element (hundreds) this way:

```
def return_basic_fhir_data(patient_bundle):
    try:
        for resource in input_bundle_json['entry']:
            if resource['resource']['resourceType'] == "Patient":
               patient_id = resource['resource']['id']
               ...
               ...
```

For example, it would be perfect to easily specify "resourceType": "Patient" and then the target element "gender": "male", "birthDate: "1974-12-25", etc. for example.

Thanks again!

*Update*

In an attempt to be a specific as possible, here is the TL;DR:

Ideally, I would be looking for something where I just need to reference the "resourceType" (Specify patient, etc.) and then it would traverse everything contained in that particular resource (flattening where appropriate).

Comment: You might try [jsonpath](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonpath-rw)

Comment: Hmm, I've taken a look, but I'm not sure if adding another dependency would be what I was looking for exactly.  It also seems like I would still need to enumerate basically everything in similar fashion.  Thanks for the suggestion though.  It looks pretty handy.

Comment: Also to add.  I'm currently prototyping in python but will be planning to rewrite in Scala for production usage.

Comment: There is a JVM/Java version of jsonpath...